# How to link external C++ library to my project on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I'm running on Mac OSX, and have a very simple C++ project where I want to use the library `jsoncpp`.

Stripped back, this is what I have:

**main.py**

```
#include <json/json.h>

...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyProject jsoncpp)
```

Attempting to build this results in the following fatal error:

`fatal error: 'json/json.h' file not found`

I assumed this is due to `jsoncpp` not being installed on my machine by default, therefore I installed it via the command `brew install jsoncpp`. I could then see what I presume are the newly installed header and object files in `/usr/local/include/json/*.h` and `/usr/local/lib/*.dylib` respectively.

However despite this I still get the same fatal error. Can anyone lend a helping hand?

This may be simple but I'm fairly new.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the linker. This is a compiler error

Comment: Use package manager for installing dependencies. For example, [Conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest).